# Unable to remove "Optional" from String

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, option-type

Below is my snippet

```
// MARK: - Location Functions
    func getCurrentLocation() -> (String!, String!) {
        let location = LocationManager.sharedInstance.currentLocation?.coordinate
        return (String(location?.latitude), String(location?.longitude))
    }

    func setCurrentLocation() {
        let (latitude, longitude) = getCurrentLocation()
        let location = "\(latitude!),\(longitude!)"
        print(location)
    }
```

Though I unwrap optional using `latitude!` and `longitude!`, it prints me `Optional(37.33233141),Optional(-122.0312186)`

I am breaking my head to remove the Optional binding.

Comment: Change to this `return (String(location?.latitude!), String(location?.longitude!))` you should add some checks though to make sure they aren't `nil` otherwise your program is going to crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your line

```
(String(location?.latitude), String(location?.longitude))
```

is the culprit.

When you call `String()` it makes a `String` of the content, but here your content is an Optional, so your String is `"Optional(...)"` (because the Optional type conforms to StringLiteralConvertible, `Optional(value)` becomes `"Optional(value)"`).

You can't remove it later, because it's now *text* representing an Optional, not an Optional String.

The solution is to fully unwrap `location?.latitude` and `location?.longitude` first.

Comment: This is THE reason why so many of us are having an issue. I wish I could share this with more people. Great Response!

Answer (score -2):

With respect to Eric D's comment, I modified the snippet to

```
// MARK: - Location Functions
func getCurrentLocation() -> (String, String) {
    let location = LocationManager.sharedInstance.currentLocation?.coordinate

    let numLat = NSNumber(double: (location?.latitude)! as Double)
    let latitude:String = numLat.stringValue

    let numLong = NSNumber(double: (location?.longitude)! as Double)
    let longitude:String = numLong.stringValue

    return (latitude, longitude)
}

func setCurrentLocation() {
    let (latitude, longitude) = getCurrentLocation()
    let location = "\(latitude),\(longitude)"
    print(location)
}
```

It worked!