# Formatting a string with optionals in swift

Tags: string, swift, format, option-type

I have a string which contains 4 optionals ... so when I print it I find

```
superString Optional("8")Optional("3")Optional("C")Optional("F")
```

I want to turn this into "83CF", a single string? I tried both of these no ...

```
 String(format:"%@%@%@%@",blah,blah)
 blah + blah + blah + blah
```

But neither works, so I tried to unwrap it with

```
if let blah = blah {
  print("Blah: \(blah)")
}
```

But the compiler complained it was a String and not an Optional!

But neither work what is going on? How do I work with these wrapped/unwrapped not so swift variables...

FIXED! was using

```
 let blah = String(stringFromData!.characters.first)
```

But needed to say ..

```
 let blah = String(stringFromData!.characters.first!)
```

Comment: Can you post the code you wrote?

Comment: Have a look at this, my answer explains what is probably your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35314279/2227743 My guess is that your string is not an optional but contains literally "Optional" in it.

Comment: Eric got it THANKS!! I unwrapped my blah and it worked!!