# Swift - How to store multiple date in default and retrieve it?

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsuserdefaults

This is my code. I want to save todayString and nextString in user default so that I can display the stored date (update every Tuesday) in label when it's not Tuesday.

```
let today = NSDate()
    let nextTue = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 6, to: today as Date)
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let todayString = formatter.string(from: today as Date)
    let nextString = formatter.string(from: nextTue!)
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"

    let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)
    let components = calendar!.components([.weekday], from: today as Date)

    if components.weekday == 3 {
        print("Hello Tuesday")
        thisWeekDate.text! = "\(todayString) - \(nextString)"

    } else {
        print("It's not Tuesday")
    }
```

[image: App design screenshot]

Comment: It seems that you compute your string every time the code will run , why you do need to save it?

Comment: @inspector_60 Because the label is not showing the date when it's not Tuesday.

Comment: Please help me to understand: only when it's Tuesday you want to print todaystring and next string, which represents the date of today and the date of next week, right?

Comment: @inspector_60 Yup but I want to keep the date after Tuesday also. I uploaded the app screenshot let u understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) saves data between runs of apps using the device storage.

The easiest way in your case would be to save two different date objects, or you can create a dictionary containing both date objects and save it instead.

Store

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(todayString, forKey: "todayStringKey")
```

Retrieve

```
let RetrivedDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "todayStringKey") as? NSDate
```

Remove - in case you want to delete it completely from storage

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "todayStringKey")
```

Comment: I print(RetrivedDate as Any), Why i get nil?

Comment: If you eventually you only need the string, you can save it instead of the date objects.

Comment: RetrivedData is not of type Any, it's of the type you saved it, which is NSDate, you should create a string from NSDate like you did in the code you posted in order to print it

Comment: I can print it, but when I put it at label it will show optional("2017-08-22"), how to delete the optional?

Comment: this is my code: thisWeekDate.text! = "\(String(describing: RetrivedDate_1)) - \(String(describing: RetrivedDate_2))"

Comment: You need to unwrap it, it's an optional you need to use if let or ?? - you cab read more about it to better understand what is unwrapping in swift

Comment: Check this out for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314279/unable-to-remove-optional-from-string

Comment: oh my god, i found some problem. if the user not download the app when it's Tuesday, the app will not run the code first, so that i can't store the data.....any solution for this case....

Comment: maybe I need to set the first day of current week to Tuesday and display the first date on label before the weekly update code. how to change the first day of current week?

Comment: Added to New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810305/how-to-set-the-first-day-of-current-week-to-tuesday-in-swift