# How to set the first day of current week to Tuesday in Swift?

Tags: swift3, nsdate

How to set the first day of current week to Tuesday in Swift 3? The schedule will update every Tuesday so the first day have to start from Tuesday.

and then display on label :

```
thisWeekDate.text! = "\(first day of current week) - \(last day of current week)"
```

Full code.

```
let today = NSDate()
    let nextTue = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 6, to: today as Date)
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let todayString = formatter.string(from: today as Date)
    let nextString = formatter.string(from: nextTue!)
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"

    let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)
    let components = calendar!.components([.weekday], from: today as Date)

    //Label code
    thisWeekDate.text! = "\(first day of current week) - \(last day of current week)"

    //If i can change the first day of current week this weekly update code can be deleted
    if components.weekday == 3 { 
        print("Hello Tuesday")
        thisWeekDate.text! = "\(todayString) - \(nextString)"

        UserDefaults.standard.set(todayString, forKey: "todayStringKey")
        _ = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "todayStringKey") as? String
        UserDefaults.standard.set(nextString, forKey: "nextStringKey")
        _ = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "nextStringKey") as? String

    } else {
        print("It's not Tuesday")
        let RetrivedDate_1 = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "todayStringKey") as? String
        let RetrivedDate_2 = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "nextStringKey") as? String

        if let date_1 = RetrivedDate_1, let date_2 = RetrivedDate_2 {
            thisWeekDate.text! = "\(date_1) - \(date_2)"
        }


    }
```

App Design Screenshot

[image: App design screenshot]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create a custom Gregorian calendar and set the first weekday to Tuesday

```
var customCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
customCalendar.firstWeekday = 3
```

Then you can get the week interval with

```
var startDate = Date()
var interval = TimeInterval()
customCalendar.dateInterval(of: .weekOfMonth, start: &startDate, interval: &interval, for: Date())
let endDate = startDate.addingTimeInterval(interval - 1)
print(startDate, endDate)
```

Comment: How can you get an array of Dates of the current week starting on Monday?

Comment: @LeeProbert Set `firstWeekday` to 2, create an array `var dateArray = [Date]()` then use a loop `for i in 0..<7 { let date = customCalendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: i, to: startDate);  dateArray.append(date) }`.

Comment: With this you would need startDate to be the Monday though right?

Comment: I asked a question on Stack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51825079/get-an-array-of-dates-of-the-current-week-starting-on-monday

Comment: Yes, `firstWeekday = 2` is Monday.

Comment: In your code startDate = Date(), so this could be any day of the week. In my code I am trying to get all of the days of the week that a date is in, regardless of which day that is.

Comment: No, `startDate` is an `inout` parameter. It is set to the actual start date in `dateInterval(of:start:interval:for`

Comment: Hey @vadian, thanks for the answer, but are the first two lines of code all that's needed to get this to work? print(customCalendar.weekdaySymbols) will print ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"] with this code. Or did I not understand how this works?

Comment: @CristianMoisei The question is about to tell the calendar to start the week at a different weekday.

Comment: @vadian, thanks for the reply. Yes, that is what I am trying to do. So then if I were to print .weekdaySymbols, should the week not start on Tuesday with the code above? For some context, I have a tableView that I am trying to populate with the days of the week, so if I changed the calendar's .firstWeekday to 3, should the tableview not display Tue, Wed, Thu..? It seems to be the same even with the .iso8601 calendar

Comment: The order of the weekday symbols is fixed corresponding to their integer representation.

Comment: Oh, ok, that makes sense. Thank you.