# Get an Array of Dates of the current week starting on Monday

Tags: swift, date

I have this code currently:

```
public var daysOfWeek: [Date]? {

    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let today = self
    let dayOfWeek = calendar.component(.weekday, from: today)
    if let weekdays = calendar.range(of: .weekday, in: .weekOfYear, for: today){

        let days = (weekdays.lowerBound ..< weekdays.upperBound).compactMap {
            calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0 - dayOfWeek, to: today)
        }
        return days
    }else{
        return nil
    }
}
```

This is an extension of the Date object.

I need to do the same thing, but have the Calendar return me the days of the week starting with Monday and not Sunday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to get the first day of the week using iso8601 calendar where the first weekday is Monday and add from 0 to 6 days to it. Try like this:

```
extension Calendar {
    static let iso8601 = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
}
extension Date {
    var startOfWeek: Date {
        return Calendar.iso8601.date(from: Calendar.iso8601.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self))!
    }
    var daysOfWeek: [Date] {
        let startOfWeek = self.startOfWeek
        return (0...6).compactMap{ Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0, to: startOfWeek)}
    }
}
```

---

```
Date().daysOfWeek  // ["Aug 13, 2018 at 12:00 AM", "Aug 14, 2018 at 12:00 AM", "Aug 15, 2018 at 12:00 AM", "Aug 16, 2018 at 12:00 AM", "Aug 17, 2018 at 12:00 AM", "Aug 18, 2018 at 12:00 AM", "Aug 19, 2018 at 12:00 AM"]
```

Comment: I ran your code (thanks), but I still get yesterday (Sunday) as the first date in the array.

Comment: There is no way to get Sunday using iso8601. Make sure you use date formatter to display your date properly localized

Comment: Yes. It works. Printing to the console gave me: 2018-08-12 23:00:00 +0000 - I wish it wouldn't do that.

Comment: You can also  print `date.description(with: .current)` to print your date using current locale